# Get class of boxed type from class of primitive type

Tags: scala

If I have value:

```
val i: Int = 1
```

I can get its class:

```
> i.getClass
res1: Class[Int] = int
```

and class of boxed value:

```
> i.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass
res2: Class[_ <: AnyRef] = class java.lang.Integer
```

The question is how to get class of boxed type from class of any primitive type without having a value, for example it should return `Class[java.lang.Integer]` for `Class[Int]`, `Class[java.lang.Float]` for `Class[Float]` and so on?

I mean this kind of function:

```
def boxedClass[T]: Class[AnyRef] = ...
```

Comment: Obviously, you are not going to use .asInstanceOf on production? this is unsafe. Did you try to use pattern matching ???

Comment: @Pavel I'm not using any of this code in production. I'm just asking. I do not know how pattern matching could help here. Please provide your answer if you have any idea.

Comment: There's `Int.box`, but I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: I don't think there's a one-to-one mapping of these types via reflection. But since there's a small finite set of them it shouldn't be to hard to map them yourself.

Comment: Is that what are you trying to do ???:  def getAny() :AnyVal = {
  val d : Int = 1
  d
 } 
 
 def getMyType() : Any = {
  val ar = getAny()
  ar match {
   case a:Int => Int
  }
 } 
 
 println( getMyType )

Comment: I want to get class of boxed type from class of primitive type. I clarified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work in scala 2.11.x and 2.12.x, a little bit to my own surprise.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

scala> class Boxed[T <: AnyVal] { def apply[R <: AnyRef]()(implicit conv: T => R, tag: ClassTag[R]) = tag.runtimeClass }
defined class Boxed

scala> def boxedClass[T <: AnyVal] = new Boxed[T]
boxedClass: [T <: AnyVal]=> Boxed[T]

scala> boxedClass[Int]()
res5: Class[_] = class java.lang.Integer

scala> boxedClass[Double]()
res6: Class[_] = class java.lang.Double
```

It works by fixing `T` to the type you want the boxed class of, and then looking for a conversion of `T` to a type `R` that is a subtype of `AnyRef`. Then you take the `ClassTag[R]` and you have the class you're looking for.

---

A fancier solution would be:

```
sealed trait BoxedClass[T <: AnyVal] { 
  type R <: AnyRef
  def clazz: Class[R] 
}

object BoxedClass {
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag
  implicit def mkBoxedClass[T <: AnyVal, R0 <: AnyRef](
    implicit 
    conv: T => R0, 
    tag: ClassTag[R0]) = 
      new BoxedClass[T] { 
        type R=R0
        val clazz = tag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[R]] 
      }
}

def boxedClass[T <: AnyVal](implicit b: BoxedClass[T]): Class[b.R] = b.clazz
```

Usage:

```
scala> boxedClass[Int]
res0: Class[Integer] = class java.lang.Integer

scala> boxedClass[Long]
res1: Class[Long] = class java.lang.Long
```

---

Also note that this will not work anymore if you define or import any other implicit conversions from `Int` to a type that extends `AnyRef`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to play with `Predef` implicits but I missed `Boxed.apply` part.